# How do I fit the entire 'Recolor Artwork...' pop up into my illustrator window

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I'm running into this frustrating problem ever since the latest adobe update. They changed the design of the 'Recolor Artwork...' function, and now when I click it the window seems to be hidden behind the toolbar. Here's a screenshot of how it looks:

[image]

I don't know if it's just a glitch, or if it's just that badly designed...but I have no idea how to get illustrator to show the entire window. I don't even see a way to resize or close the window. Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this? I need to use this function to recolor a bunch of graphics for print.

Comment: There are **minimum** system requirements -- [Oct 2020 release] - 1024 x 768 display (1920 x 1080 recommended). If you can't get 768 pixels in height, you may need to adjust your screen resolution if possible.

Comment: Image is 2624x1584 & '144 dpi' which may indicate it's a HiDPI/Retina issue, but that would be a computer support issue, not a graphics one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, even on a 768 pixel height laptop. Just go to windows taskbar setting, change this to "auto hide taskbar", then choose "essentials" view for illustrator. These 2 changes will give you an extra 80ish pixels height for workspace, which is enough. I have gone from not being able to see edges or move the recolour window, to having full access to it.